# Laravel 5 Validation Trim

Tags: php, laravel, trim

I am a beginner in Laravel 5.

How can I remove whitespaces in validator?? i have read the documentation but there is no validator for trim(remove whitespaces).

here my rules

```
$rules = [
        'name' =>'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'address' => 'required',
        'phones' => 'required'
    ];
```

thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following code to trim all string input (as you might have arrays in the input)

```
    // trim all input
    Input::merge(array_map(function ($value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            return trim($value);
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }, Input::all()));
```

Comment: or you can just use the ternary operator 
`return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;`

 by the way, the op should choose this answer.

Answer (score 9):

It's not job for validator to change any input data. Trim validator exists in CodeIgniter, but as to me this isn't right place to perform trim.

You can automatically trim all input by using using this:

```php
Input::merge(array_map('trim', Input::all()));
```

Now do the rest of your coding:

```php
$username = Input::get('username'); // it's trimed 
// ...
Validator::make(...);
```

Comment: This does not support arrays. @Alex answer is better.

Comment: you should do this but this is not the currenct way you should use middleware

Answer (score 5):

Due to the documention [laravel HTTP Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization)
by default laravel trim all the requests data.

---

and `Trim` the request in validation part is so dirty job.
You could manage this feature like `trim` or `convert empty string to null` with the [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

because middleware execute before the validation and you could have clean data in validation

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.2 or 5.3 you can use trim for spaces remove like this

`$input = array_map('trim', $request->all());`

so this will remove all space form inputs that posted and validation will work fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in your request file.

```
$input = request()->all();
$input['url'] = trim($input['url']);
request()->replace($input);
```

You can also create an `all()` function in your request file to update request parameters:

```
 public function all()
    {
        $all = parent::all(); // $this->all();
        $all['new_key'] = "new_data";
        $all['old_key'] = "new_data";

        return $all;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function formatInput()
{
  $input = array_map('trim', $this->all());
  $this->replace($input);
  return $this->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the `FormRequest` class and overrode the `prepareForValidation` method which is called before validation happens.

```
// anything I don't want trimmed here
protected $untrimmable = [];

// replace the request with trimmed request here
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    return $this->replace($this->trimData($this->all()));
}

// recursively trim the fields in the request here
protected function trimData($data,$keyPrefix = '')
{
    $trimmedFields = array_map(function($value,$field) use ($keyPrefix){
        // if the value is an array handle it as
        // a request array and send along the prefix
        if(is_array($value)){
            return $this->trimData($value,$this->dotIndex($keyPrefix,$field));
        }

        // if the field is not in the specified fields to be
        // left untrimmed
        if(
            !in_array($this->dotIndex($keyPrefix,$field),$this->dontTrim) && 
            !in_array($this->dotIndex($keyPrefix,$field), $this->untrimmable)
        ) {
            return trim((string) $value);
        }

        return $value;

    }, $data,array_keys($data));

    return array_combine(array_keys($data),$trimmedFields);
}
```

What it does:

1. Replace request with a new one with trimmed inputs
2. Set all fields I don't want trimmed in an `untrimmable` property.
3. Handles nested inputs with dot notation .

Here's a link to the gist https://gist.github.com/msbrime/336a788c7cced2137bdc7896c1241239

Comment: Hi there, could you please not provide only a link to the source but highlight useful parts in your answer. PS: I edited your answer, please try to format your answers - especially for code

Comment: sure thing @Arount

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $r->all();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
if($value!=""){ //If your primaryKey id is autoincrement
   $data[$key] = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/',' ',$value);
}
}
$variable = new modelName($data);
$variable->save();

//Here Parameter Explaination
 => '/\s{2,}/' Pattern must write between '/ /' and \s{2,} means 2 or more than 2 spaces sholud be trim
 => ' ' second parameter is with. Means 1st parameter replace with 2nd parameter(here, one space)
 => $value is variable which is trim
```