# How to add the trim function to validation rules in Laravel Request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-formrequest

I have a validation rule as shown below. I am using **exists** to ensure that the contract is unique. The issue now is that contract numbers are stored with spaces in the database so this validation is not working for those cases (for example it will say the contract number does not exist which is due to the space before the number). To solve this, I want to do trim(contract_number). Please how can I apply the trim function to the **contract_number** below?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [   
        'tel' => 'required|max:25',
        'contract' => 'required|digits:9|exists:accounts,contract_number',
        'nom' => 'required|max:255',
        'language' => 'required|max:2',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Will not help much, but why are the contract numbers stored (in database) with a space before them? Any good reason?

Comment: you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386203/laravel-5-validation-trim

Comment: @Mubin Laravel uses the `TrimStrings` middleware, so all inputs should already be trimmed. The "problem" is that data _in the database_ has a string before them

Comment: Hi @kerbh0lz, I think the info in that field where imported from an excel file hence the spaces in some cases

Comment: Instead of dealing with custom validators (and possibly other custom parts of code) that deal with those spaces personally I would just get rid of the spaces in the database

Comment: Hi @kerbh0lz, the database has more than 2 million records. We have asked the DBA to remove the spaces in the database but he recommended that we should trim at the application level.

Comment: Is your DBA the one who wrongly imported the data in the first place? ;) Was just a suggestion, I'd rather have clean data and _never ever_ have to deal with that problem again.

Comment: I think is another team that imported the data wrongly

Comment: @FokwaBest Does I answer your question? You can check my answer's in the list

Comment: Hi @BasheerKharoti, Thanks for your answer but how do I add the trim function to the contract number coming from the database using your approach? You know the contract number are stored in the database with spaces so when the user enter the contract number in the form and click validate, it says it doesn't exist due to the space. I know trimming before validating will solve the problem.

Comment: Something like `'contract' => 'required|digits:9|exists:accounts,trim(contract_number)'`

Comment: @FokwaBest Laravel does trimming out of the box. See `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: Hi @BasheerKharoti, the contract number is not coming from the form, It is coming from the database. Does laravel also trim info coming from DB out of the box? The issue I am facing is this, we have a form with contract number field, when user enter his contract number and click "Check", some are not found because they are stored with spaces before them in the database.

Comment: @FokwaBest see my updated answer

Comment: Hi @BasheerKharoti, Thanks alot. Your answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests), you can use `withValidator` method on **Custom Form Request** to add any further validations on the `request`. Remove the rule `exists:accounts,trim(contract_number)` from the list, and try custom rule with `after` hook.

```
/**
* Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if (!\DB::table('accounts')->whereRaw('TRIM(contract_number) = ?', [request('contract_number')])->exists()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('contract_number', 'Contract number does not exists');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @BasheerKharoti, thanks a lot. This solution works